# Windows with Full Control to Everyone for Everything

Tags: windows-7, administrator, acl

Similar to [sudo chmod -R 777 /](https://superuser.com/questions/300743/sudo-chmod-r-777), but for Windows 7. A customer decided he hated the prompts for administrators to continue, so he gave himself Full Control for the Everyone group on Windows 7. Now, some fun issues ensued:

1. Programs do not install
2. Items normally requiring an Administrator do not run or show the `CONSENT.EXE` program asking permission
3. UAC is still on, but not activating (Yes, I checked)
4. System Restore does not fix this.

What I would love in an ideal world (which I know is not always the case) is a script that would set the permissions of all the default Windows items in the NTFS ACL list. Barring that, I do understand that a re-install would be necessary... However, since a "repair" install requires Administrative rights, I have a weird feeling it would be a clean install. I don't mind, but it may show the customer that he should ask next time :-P

**EDIT** Update...

I tried [avirk](https://superuser.com/users/86550/avirk)'s solution, but that did not work. I also tried [soandos](https://superuser.com/users/82812/soandos)'s answer of running `icacls * /T /Q /C /RESET`, but to no avail. I have done a repair install, and am evaluating how it acts (installing updates, installing software, etc).

Comment: You can also try [SubInAcl](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2006/09/04/739820.aspx) to fix installation error.

Comment: @avirk Why not post that as an answer? I'll try both yours and soandos' answer tomorrow when I get onto his computer

Comment: @avirk Just read everything on the site, made a batch file for it, and will try tomorrow morning

Comment: @avirk Nope, that technique did not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it turns out that it affects Windows enough that a FULL re-install is all that would fix this. I backed up the user data I could find, wiped the C:\, and reloaded Windows from scratch

Answer (score 3):

Use:
`icacls * /T /Q /C /RESET`

If that does not work you can reset the permissions manually.

If the only thing that that was changed is that `Everyone` was granted full control to everything, then the solution would be to take away all permissions for everything, then give it read permissions to the necessary system files (Program files, etc).

You can do this though the GUI option in windows explorer (make sure to apply this change to all subfolders as well), or using the `icacls` command, with the `/T` flag.

Comment: Tried, but installs still fail. I do, however, have the `CONSENT.EXE` UAC prompt appearing now :) I ran the command as admin in the recovery console, since CMD wouldn't open for me as an elevated user

Comment: The manual way failed as well?

Comment: I don't know the extent of the permissions and what all should be applied where. I'm going to try the SubInACL tip above today