# Windows Vista SP2 access denied to c: drive (RESOLVED)

Tags: windows, windows-vista, permissions

I have inadvertently managed to remove all permissions to my C: drive so now its become read only and is obviously causing numerous problems.

I have tried booting in safe mode with command prompt and using the hidden Administrator account but whenever I try commands such as takeown and icacls all I get is 'Access denied' so I'm now at a loss as to how to reset the permissions so I can regain control.

..any help/ideas much appreciated before I format and do a clean Vista install!!

Jim

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/436913/windows-with-full-control-to-everyone-for-everything

Answer (score 0):

Quick update - I've now resolved this by removing the offending drive, inserting it into a USB caddy, then on a Windows 7 laptop, I managed to take ownership and then set the owner to SYSTEM and I now have full access once more!!